# Comparing two spans using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having issues trying to see if a span contains another one.
So, i have a draggable item which needs to be in another span to display a message.
How could i check using jquery or javascript if my span #piece is IN the span #answer ?

Thank you

Comment: if ($('#answer').find('#piece').length )

Comment: Do you mean *in* as `span#piece` is a child element of `span#answer`? Or do you mean that the `span#piece` is visually appearing as if it's inside/ontop of the `span#answer` (since you're mentioning it's draggable)?

Comment: yes i mean that the `span#piece` is visually appearing ontop of the other one :)

Comment: are you using jqueryui for draggable or native html5?

Comment: i'm using jqueryui :)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `contains`. Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

**Edit:**

You'll need to convert the first argument to a DOM element though. If that's not trivial to do, `find` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#answer').find('#piece').length == 1)
// your span is inside
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am still having some issues: i created a button to check if it's inside and displays "hello" if it is. but the button displays the message even if my span didn't move. Here's the code: `$("#ok").click(function(){
        if($('#ans5').find('#nb1').length == 1);
        alert("hello");
    });`